# A C routine to round a float to n significant digits?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Suppose I have a `float`.  I would like to round it to a certain number of significant digits.

In my case `n=6`.

So say float was `f=1.23456999;`

`round(f,6)` would give `1.23457`

`f=123456.0001`  would give `123456`

Anybody know such a routine ?

Here it works on website: http://ostermiller.org/calc/significant_figures.html

Comment: convert it to char then cut the last N digits out.

Comment: @pyCthon : but you need to check the cutting edge whether it's  greater than 5 or not

Comment: Do you need to output it to an interactive terminal or file, or are you merely looking to round it prior to doing more work with it in memory?

Answer (score 10):

Multiply the number by a suitable scaling factor to move all significant digits to the left of the decimal point. Then round and finally reverse the operation:

```
#include <math.h>

double round_to_digits(double value, int digits)
{
    if (value == 0.0) // otherwise it will return 'nan' due to the log10() of zero
        return 0.0;

    double factor = pow(10.0, digits - ceil(log10(fabs(value))));
    return round(value * factor) / factor;   
}
```

Tested: http://ideone.com/fH5ebt

Buts as @PascalCuoq pointed out: the rounded value may not exactly representable as a floating point value.

Comment: Starting to look very similar to my solution now. ;-)

Comment: Yes, true. Sorry about that ;-) I upvoted you! But there isn't a `round` in the C library, or is there? I always implemented it manually.

Comment: Yes, there's `round` and `roundf`, for `double` and `float` respectively, in `<math.h>`.

Comment: Thanks - But I'm not going to update my solution, to keep it different from yours ;-)

Comment: You should have tested it like this: http://ideone.com/WK4G51 . It didn't work. Your new version produces this: http://ideone.com/6dskEv . Is this what you intended?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Actually, yes. The thing is, -123.567 cannot be represented exactly in floating point, so there will, of course, be a rounding error (even `printf("%.52g\n", 1234.56789);` doesn't "work"). If the OP requires a floating point result, then my function is a close as possible to the desired result.

Comment: There is that, and there is the fact that your function keeps more digits than asked for on the inputs in the test.

Comment: I just tried your version, and it's really beyond floating errors. Multiplying by 10^digits and rounding doesn't keep a number of digits of precision. Think of using your function with `0.000123` and `2` digits. It will output `0.0` (which is wrong, isn't it?)

Comment: @PascalCuoq and Massimiliano: you are of course both correct! I corrected the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: But I still didn't get it quiet right. Let me think. Ok - fixed the printf.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Round(float f, int d)
{
    char buf[16];
    sprintf(buf, "%.*g", d, f);
    return strdup(buf);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *r = Round(1.23456999, 6);
    printf("%s\n", r);
    free(r);
}
```

Output is:

> 1.23457

Comment: It turns out to be a lot simpler than I first thought. :)

Comment: Why free(r).. could you please make me understand ?

Comment: @Omkant: It prevents the memory from leaking. When you're done with the memory that contains the string, you should `free` it so memory can be used for something else.

Comment: Oh yeah got it.. the memory allocated in strdup ..right?..I missed it at first sight..

Comment: @Omkant: Correct. You could also make the function take a pointer to a buffer to stuff the result in.

Comment: That isn't generating a rounded float value, though; it's just generating a string (char *) and printing it out.

Comment: @Kaitain Which is what you have to do. There's no point in rounding to a value that's not exact -- you'd just have to round it again.

Comment: So there would be no point in having a routine that took an input of e.g. 1.89f and returned 1.9f? The only thing you can hope to do is print out a truncated representation of the underlying value?

Comment: @Kaitain Exactly. You picked a perfect example, since the value 1.9 cannot be represented exactly by a float, only approximately. So the value wouldn't even be 1.9 but something you could round to 1.9 when you converted it into some other form like a string. (So you would have rounded it to 1.9 by converting it to something you could later round to 1.9? Does that make any sense?)

Comment: There seem to be two orthogonal issues being discussed here:
1. Truncating the actual value of a float
2. Displaying the value of a float as an aesthetic truncation

Consider this code
'float f1 = 1.89f;
float f2 = 1.9f;
bool areEqual = ( f1 == f2 );'

areEqual is clearly false. Now consider this code:

float f1 = truncateTo1dp( 1.89f );
float f2 = 1.9f;
bool areEqual = ( f1 == f2 );

Is there an implementation of truncateTo1dp that would leave the value areEqual as true? Yes.

Comment: @Kaitain There's only one issue unless you try to do this incorrectly. Yes, you have a representation problem if you try to represent the rounded value in a float. But the simple fix is just to not do that (bluntly, that's a pretty silly thing to do anyway). Then there's only one issue.

Comment: No. Two separate issues.

Comment: @Kaitain Okay then, I give up, what's the third issue? One issue is how to display a rounded value, we agree on that. The issue of how to represent the rounded value as a float is not relevant, for the reason I explained. What's the third issue?

Comment: How would your "Round" function satisfy the requirements I outlined above, i.e. leaving areEqual as true? (Let's say that my putative function truncateTo1DP calls into Round).

Comment: @Kaitain I don't think it's possible for any function to guarantee that. There could be two equally close representations for `1.9`. As I said, rounding to a rounded value is just not sensible. If you're going to round something, your output representation has to be capable of exactly holding the rounded result.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
double round_to_n_digits(double x, int n)
{ 
    double scale = pow(10.0, ceil(log10(fabs(x))) + n);

    return round(x * scale) / scale;
}
```

Alternatively you could just use `sprintf`/`atof` to convert to a string and back again:

```
double round_to_n_digits(double x, int n)
{ 
    char buff[32];

    sprintf(buff, "%.*g", n, x);

    return atof(buff);
}
```

Test code for both of the above functions: http://ideone.com/oMzQZZ

---

Note that in some cases incorrect rounding may be observed, e.g. as pointed out by [@clearScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2190313/clearscreen) in the comments below, 13127.15 is rounded to 13127.1 instead of 
13127.2.

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that using IEEE 754 to represent decimal rounding is dubious, the first function you wrote (and tested) keeps more digits than asked for: http://ideone.com/wi4pqe

Comment: @Pascal: you're confusing rounding with representation - the rounded value can only be represented within the finite accuracy of a floating point data type, but it's as accurate as it can be within this limitation. No implementation that retains the original data type (double) can do any better than this.

Comment: That's the part I did not want to discuss. I must insist that it is possible to do better than `round_to_n_digits_1` in your ideone code. Your function `round_to_n_digits_2` does. See link.

Comment: 13127.15 is rounded off to 13127.1 by both the functions. This is wrong - it should be rounded off to 13127.2

Comment: @clearScreen: yes, I see the problem, but I'm not sure there's an easy fix - any suggestions, or should I just delete this answer ?

Comment: If you use float instead of double, you get the required answer. But I don't know why this happens.

Comment: @PaulR , except for the above mentioned case, it works fine

Comment: Thanks - I'll leave the answer up then, but maybe edit in a caveat.

Answer (score 3):

This should work (except the noise given by floating point precision):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double dround(double a, int ndigits);

double dround(double a, int ndigits) {

  int    exp_base10 = round(log10(a));
  double man_base10 = a*pow(10.0,-exp_base10);
  double factor     = pow(10.0,-ndigits+1);  
  double truncated_man_base10 = man_base10 - fmod(man_base10,factor);
  double rounded_remainder    = fmod(man_base10,factor)/factor;

  rounded_remainder = rounded_remainder > 0.5 ? 1.0*factor : 0.0;

  return (truncated_man_base10 + rounded_remainder)*pow(10.0,exp_base10) ;
}

int main() {

  double a = 1.23456999;
  double b = 123456.0001;

  printf("%12.12f\n",dround(a,6));
  printf("%12.12f\n",dround(b,6));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print a float to a string use simple [`sprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/). For outputting it just to the console you can use [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/):

```
printf("My float is %.6f", myfloat);
```

This will output your float with 6 decimal places.

Comment: That will give you 6 decimal places, not 6 significant digits.

Comment: You are right I just didn't know the right english word for that.

Comment: If you use `%.6g` you will get 6 significant digits.

Comment: This just prints it, but won't convert it for you

Comment: @PaulR, you should include that as an answer.

Comment: @pyCthon: It converts it before it prints it. If you want to save the output to a string, use `sprintf`.

Comment: @Vlad - I'm looking for rounded to n sig.  Or closest number to the f in question but having n sig digits.

Answer (score -2):

> Print to 16 significant digit.

```
double x = -1932970.8299999994;
char buff[100];
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.16g", x);
std::string buffAsStdStr = buff;

std::cout << std::endl << buffAsStdStr ;
```